# ¿Por qué se genera un campo LONGTEXT en vez de un JSON en una migración Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, json, mariadb

**CONTEXTO**

Estoy aprendiendo Laravel 7.x con estas herramientas:

1. XAMPP con PHP 7.4.7
2. MySQL (MariaDB): 10.4.13 ([ver captura](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4TRz.png))

**PROBLEMA**

En la [documentación oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#creating-columns) se indica que para generar un campo tipo JSON en una tabla mediante una migración, basta con poner: `$table->json('phone_numbers');`

Siempre que ejecuto la migración (`php artisan migrate`), efectivamente se genera el campo *phone_numbers*, pero con tipo LONGTEXT, no con tipo JSON, tal como se ve en [esta captura](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hORgs.png). Claramente mi Base de datos sí soporta el tipo JSON ([ver esta otra captura](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bwkv.png)).

En todas mis búsquedas encuentro que para generar un campo JSON hay que hacer justo lo que dice la doucmentación.

Cualquier sugerencia y ayuda es bienvenida.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Empecemos por aclarar unos puntos:

- Estás usando MariaDB y no MySQL no los debemos confundir
- MariaDB propone el almacenar estructuras JSON con un tipo de dato `LONGTEXT` desde la versión 10.2.7, esto por y cito<sup>1</sup>:

> JSON is an alias for LONGTEXT introduced for compatibility reasons
> with MySQL's JSON data type. MariaDB implements this as a LONGTEXT
> rather, as the JSON data type contradicts the SQL standard, and
> MariaDB's benchmarks indicate that performance is at least equivalent.

Que se puede traducir como:

> JSON es un alias para LONGTEXT introducido por razones de
> compatibilidad con el tipo de datos JSON de MySQL. MariaDB implementa
> esto como un LONGTEXT, ya que el tipo de datos JSON contradice el
> estándar SQL, y los *benchmarks* de MariaDB indican que el
> rendimiento es al menos equivalente.

- De todos modos aunque el dato en tu tabla no sea explícitamente JSON, tendrás a tu disposición todas las funciones de que dispone el motor para manipular los datos almacenados con dicha estructura

Por ejemplo yo tengo instalado *MariaDB Server versión 10.4.7* y si creo una tabla cuya columna sea de tipo *JSON* así:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla(
   datos JSON
);
```

Cuando le haga un `DESCRIBE` a dicha entidad, obtendré una salida como esta:

```
"datos" "longtext"  "YES"
```

Sin embargo para MySQL es otra historia, con la misma sintaxis en la versión 8.0.20 obtendrás en el `DESCRIBE` esta salida:

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
datos   json    YES
```

- <sup>1</sup>[JSON datatype MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-data-type/)
- [Checar si la estructura JSON es válida](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_valid/)
- [Funciones JSON en MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-functions/)

Comment: Gracias, @BetaM, tu respuesta es absolutamente esclarecedora!

Answer (score 0):

Te diria que depende de tu motor de base de datos, de todos modos los campos longtext te sirven para guardar JSON.
Te paso un link donde esta  bien detallado como puedes trabajar con los campos JSON cuando creas una migracion.
https://laraveles.com/como-usar-de-forma-correcta-el-campo-json-de-mysql/